# Better way to get 15 tables results at a time in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, database-optimization

I have about 20 tables. These tables have only id (primary key) and description (varchar). The data is a lot reaching about 400 rows for one table.

Right now I have to get data of at least 15 tables at a time. 
Right now I am calling them one by one. Which means that in one session I am giving 15 calls. This is making my process slow.

Can any one suggest any better way to get the results from the database?

I am using `MySQL database` and using `Java Springs` on server side. Will making view for all combined help me ? 
The application is becoming slow because of this issue and I need a solution that will make my process faster.

Comment: 400 rows - wow - better call NASA.

But really you need to supply more infor here.

Perhaps you could make what ever is making these 15 calls do it is an Async manner?

Comment: I think you miss the picture. 400 rows for the table it is like 1 penny in your pocket - nothing for MySQL, so 15 calls of nothing should take almost no time. So what do you call slow? do you have any proof? can you provide your real db schema? query samples? sqlfiddle would be very helpful. how do you track the performance?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l91ISfcuzDw

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your schema isn't so great. 20 tables of id/varchar sounds like a broken EAV, which is generally considered broken to begin with. Just the same, I think a UNION query will help out. This would be the "View" to create in the database so you can just `SELECT * FROM thisviewyoumade` and let it worry about the hitting all the tables.

A UNION query works by having multiple `SELECT` stataements "Stacked" on top of one another. It's important that each `SELECT` statement has the same number, ordinal, and types of fields so when it stacks the results, everything matches up.

In your case, it makes sense to manufacturer an extra field so you know which table it came from. Something like the following:

```
SELECT 'table1' as tablename, id, col2 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2', id, col2 FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table3', id, col2 FROM table3
... and on and on
```

The names or aliases of the fields in the first `SELECT` statement are the field names that are used in the result set that is returned, so no worries about doing a bunch `AS blahblahblah` in subsequent `SELECT` statements.

The real question is whether this union query will perform faster than 15 individual calls on such a tiny tiny tiny amount of data. I think the better option would be to change your schema so this stuff is already stored in one table just like this UNION query outputs. Then you would need a single select statement against a single table. And 400x20=8000 is still a dinky little table to query.

Answer (score 0):

To get a row of all descriptions into app code in a single roundtrip send a query kind of

```
select t1.description, ... t15.description
from  t -- this should contain all needed ids
join table1 t1 on t1.id = t.t1id
...
join table1 t15 on t15.id = t.t15id
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get you what you really need but here merging all those table values into single table 
    CREATE TABLE table_name AS (

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID AND
  ...
  LEFT JOIN tableN tN ON tN-1.ID=tN.ID

)
```